# Trying to include R Code with listings package

Tags: listings, r

I was trying to include some R Code in a simple LaTeX document, but for some reason I could not do it. I put the R Code in the same directory (I also tried putting the full directory for my R Code) of the TeX document, but I have as output a PDF document with this: `\lstinputlisting{Ra.R}`

This is my LaTeX document. What I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\lstset{ %
  language=R,                     % the language of the code
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,       % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line
                                  % will be numbered
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},  % choose the background color. You must add \usepackage{color}
  showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
  showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
  showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  frame=single,                   % adds a frame around the code
  rulecolor=\color{black},        % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. commens (green here))
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=false,        % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  title=\lstname,                 % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting;
                                  % also try caption instead of title
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},      % keyword style
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},   % comment style
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},      % string literal style
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},         % if you want to add a comment within your code
  morekeywords={*,...}            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
} 

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
\lstinputlisting{Ra.R}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Nice listing for R code. Tks specially for the comment. really usefull.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`\lstinputlisting{}` should not be inside a `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}` pair. Remove the begin and end and it should work as expected.

Comment: The best way to thank @BrianDiggs is to accept his answer, and upvote it.

Answer (score 11):

I have no sufficient reputation to comment, so I will point out that you need to include

```
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
```

after the `color` package.